# Why are 'di' and 'dal' interchangeable in some cases, while they aren't in others?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> sono quasi morto ***di*** freddo
>
> sono quasi morto ***dal*** freddo

Can anyone explain what preposition I should prefer in the above sentence?

And, always in reference to above sentences, supposing they are interchangeable there, can anyone explain why they are not in cases below.

> sono quasi morto ***di*** morbillo
>
> sono quasi morto ***dal*** morbillo

Comment: Great question. I wanted to ask about it, too.

Comment: I don't know precisely why, but I could use *morto dal freddo* and not *morto dal morbillo*.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is quite subtle.
When you use "dal" actually you are meaning "dal troppo" ("because of too much").

For example, "sono quasi morto dal freddo" means "sono quasi morto dal [troppo] freddo" (I almost died because of too much cold), while "sono quasi morto di freddo" simply means "I almost died because of the cold". The meaning therefore is almost identical.

This is the reason why you can say "sono quasi morto dal freddo" but you can't say "sono quasi morto dal morbillo" since "too much measles" is meaningless: you just have or not have measles.

Answer (score 2):

As Domenico already said `dal` is a shorthand for `dal troppo` and it *always* describe a *causal* relationship. `di` *can* provide a causal relationship but it does *not* have to.

For example, [La Stampa](http://www.lastampa.it/2013/09/19/scienza/benessere/sensazione-di-troppo-caldo-o-freddo-colpa-della-tiroide-TIJqreJA7T5BfKUuZClm3K/pagina.html) uses `Sensazione di troppo caldo o freddo` (feeling of too much heat or cold). Here you can *not* use `dal`, as in `sensazione dal caldo` or `sensazione dal troppo caldo`, because there is no causal relationship. It's a specification about the kind of feeling.